# Index not used Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Tracking indexes and analyzing the tables on which index add, we encounter some situations:
some of our tables have index, but when I execute a query with a clause `where` on index field, doesn't account in your idx_scan field respective. Same relname and schemaname, so, I couldn't be wrong.

Testing more, I deleted and create the table again, after that the query returned to account the `idx_scan`.

That occurred with another tables too, we executed some queries with indexes and didn't account idx_scan field, only in seq_scan and even if I create another field in the same table with index, this new field doesn't count idx_scan.

Whats the problem with these tables? What do we do wrong? Only if I create a new table with indexes that account in idx_scan, just in an old table that has wrong.
We did migration sometimes with this database, maybe it can be the problem? Happened on localhost and server online.

Another event that we saw, some indexes were accounted, idx_scan > 0, and when execute query select, does not increase idx_scan again, the number was fixed and just increase seq_scan.
I believe those problems can be related.

I appreciate some help, it's a big mystery prowling our DB and have no idea what the problem can be.

Comment: Postgres might not use an index if it thinks a sequential scan will ultimately be faster.

Comment: Most common cause is that analyze hasn't been run yet after doing a lot of insert/delete operations on a table.  I had to explicitly run analyze during a data building process for this very reason.

Comment: I agree with you Mike, make sense what you said. And I didn't understand very well what Lucas said, I need execute analyze after include or delete a lot of registers in my table, is it? to idx_scan start to account

Comment: A very useful reading on indexes: http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: Without more detail about stats and query plan, it's hard to say why postgres declines to use your index. See [my answer here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16612/index-on-primary-key-not-used-in-simple-join/16836#16836) for some insight into ways the planner can decide the index isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A couple suggestions (and what to add to your question).

The first is that index scans are not always favored to to sequential scans.  For example, if your table is small or the planner estimates that most pages will need to be fetched, an index scan will be omitted in favor of a sequential scan.

Remember: no plan beats retrieving a single page off disk and sequentially running through it.

Similarly if you have to retrieve, say, 50% of the pages of a relation, doing an index scan is going to trade somewhat less disk/IO total for a great deal more random disk/IO.  It might be a win if you use SSD's but certainly not with conventional hard drives.  After all you don't really want to be waiting for platters to turn.  If you are using SSD's you can tweak planner settings accordingly.

So index vs sequential scan is not the end of the story.  The question is how many rows are retrieved, how big the tables are, what percentage of disk pages are retrieved, etc.

If it really is picking a bad plan (rather than a good plan that you didn't consider!) then the question becomes why.  There are ways of setting statistics targets but these may not be really helpful.

Finally the planner really can't choose an index in some cases where you might like it to.  For example, suppose I have a 10 million row table with records spanning 5 years (approx 2 million rows per year on average).  I would like to get the distinct years.  I can't do this with a standard query and index, but I can build a WITH RECURSIVE CTE to essentially execute the same query once for each year and that will use an index.  Of course you had better have an index in that case or WITH RECURSIVE will do a sequential scan for each year which is certainly not what you want!

tl;dr:  It's complicated.  You want to make sure this is really a bad plan before jumping to conclusions and then if it is a bad plan see what you can do about it depending on your configuration.